# Table row data appearing over table header when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have created multiple tables on an HTML page. I have made the header row sticky so that only the rows inside  scroll. However, on scrolling, a bit of data from the rows appear above the sticky heading rows. This is my css:

```
.table > :not(:first-child){
    border-top: 0;
}

thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
} 

thead th:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Something like this [image of overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKyIG.png)

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example? Currently you have only shared part of your CSS and the other code items are up for guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing

```
thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

to:

```
thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't keep m header row sticky

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

That was able to resolve the issue for me.